# Rails customizing the administrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, rails-administrate

I have location, concert and artist model as

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :concerts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, through: :concerts
end

class Concert < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :concerts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, through: :concerts
end
```

I'am currently using the rails administrate, now I want to customise the rails administrate gem where instead of displaying the id while adding the new concert I want to get the location and artist name there instead of there id's. I have attached the screenshot there.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Location and Artist dashboards, you need to define a `display_resource` method:

```
class LocationDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  def display_resource(location)
    location.name # or whatever attribute you want to use
  end

  # ...
end
```

Do the same in your Artist Dashboard and you should be good to go :)

For more detailed info on how to customize your dashboard check [this](https://administrate-prototype.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards)